# I deleted 95% of features in a gpkg file, using QGIS, but the file size remains the same

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I downloaded a file with all the roads in Denmark. The gpkg file was 447MB.

My project only concerns a small region, so I used QGIS to delete most of the features, so that only less than 5% of the features were left, and then saved the file. However, the file is still 447.

What is going on? And how do I reduce the size of the file?

Comment: You probably need to vacuum the database. You can do this by right-clicking the geodatabase in the browser panel once you have made a connection  to it.

Comment: Research "high water mark" in a database glossary to understand the theory. Generally speaking, it would be faster to copy out 5% of the features than to delete 95%.

Comment: see this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380158/whats-happening-with-unusually-large-geopackage-file-size)

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation of the GDAL GeoPackage driver manual https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html

> When dropping a table, or removing records from tables, the space they
> occupied is not immediately released and kept in the pool of file
> pages that SQLite may reuse later. If you need to shrink the file to
> its minimum size, you need to issue an explicit “VACUUM” SQL request.
> Note that this will result in a full rewrite of the file.

You can vacuum with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo -sql "VACUUM" my_geopackage.gpkg
```

Alternatively you can use any SQL client for SQLite because vacuum, and the need to use vacuum, comes directly from SQLite. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html

> The VACUUM command rebuilds the database file, repacking it into a
> minimal amount of disk space. There are several reasons an application
> might do this:
>
> Unless SQLite is running in "auto_vacuum=FULL" mode, when a large
> amount of data is deleted from the database file it leaves behind
> empty space, or "free" database pages. This means the database file
> might be larger than strictly necessary. Running VACUUM to rebuild the
> database reclaims this space and reduces the size of the database
> file. ...